# How to get previous URL in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

How can I get the previous URL in Next.js?
I thought the values `this.props.router.asPath` and `nextProps.router.asPath` are different.

Actually, I want to call `router.push` after login. I know that `router.back` goes to the previous page. But it's possible to go to another site. The users having history stacks go to the previous page, the users not having history stacks go to `/` main page.

```jsx
import { Component } from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import ErrorComponent from '@/components/error'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const { Component, pageProps, router } = this.props;
    const props = {
      ...pageProps,
      router
    }
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Container>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Container>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // previous page url /contents
    console.log(this.props.router.asPath) // /about
    console.log(nextProps.router.asPath) // /about
    console.log('window.history.previous.href', window.history.previous) // undefined
  }
}
```

How can I fix it? Or how can I get the previous URL to move page after login?

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65614253/10367188

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can implement a custom history in global state

Something like this

**_app.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {};

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }

        return { pageProps };
    }

    state = {
        history: [] // keep history items in state
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { asPath } = this.props.router;

        // lets add initial route to `history`
        this.setState(prevState => ({ history: [...prevState.history, asPath] }));
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { history } = this.state;
        const { asPath } = this.props.router;

        // if current route (`asPath`) does not equal
        // the latest item in the history,
        // it is changed so lets save it
        if (history[history.length - 1] !== asPath) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({ history: [...prevState.history, asPath] }));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Component history={this.state.history} {...pageProps} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

so then in your components you can navigate wherever you want within history

```js
if (!history || !history.length) {
    router.push('/');
} else {
    router.push(history[history.length - 1]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 41):

You find the Referer ( so the previous URL ) in the context of [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) or any other Data fetching methods

as

```js
context.req.headers.referer
```

example in code

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.req.headers.referer)
}
```

Comment: To save some the roundtrip - it is indeed "referer" with one r in the middle, not two

Comment: Slightly different but related to this answer I needed to get the referer in the Next.JS API preview route to redirect back to the original referer when the exit-preview route is hit, you can do this by using `request.headers.referer` where `request` is typed to `NextApiRequest`

Answer (score 17):

I've used Context do to this

In **_app.tsx**

```tsx
import { HistoryProvider } from '../contexts/History'

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Header />
        <HistoryProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </HistoryProvider>...
```

**/contexts/History.tsx**

```tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'

interface HValidation {
  history: string[]
  setHistory(data: string[]): void
  back(): void
}

const HistoryContext = createContext<HValidation>({} as HValidation)
export const HistoryProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { asPath, push, pathname } = useRouter()
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<string[]>([])

  function back() {
    for (let i = history.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      const route = history[i]
      if (!route.includes('#') && route !== pathname) {
        push(route)

        // if you want to pop history on back
        const newHistory = history.slice(0, i)
        setHistory(newHistory)

        break
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory(previous => [...previous, asPath])
  }, [asPath])

  return (
    <HistoryContext.Provider
      value={{
        back,
        history,
        setHistory,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </HistoryContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useHistory(): HValidation {
  const context = useContext(HistoryContext)
  return context
}
```

In **any component**, you can use

```tsx
import { useHistory } from '../../contexts/History'

const ContentHeader: React.FC<ContentHeaderProps> = ({ title, hideBack }) => {
    const { history, back } = useHistory() ...
```

I've used this component to back history ignoring links with hash (#), because the native **router.back()** was bugging when i have `<a href="#someid" />` to scroll page to some page ids
I wanted to go back to last page, and not the last anchor

**EDIT 01/04/2021**

You can also set a fallback route for "back".

```tsx
back(fallbackRoute?: string): void

function back(fallbackRoute?: string) {
  for (let i = history.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    const route = history[i]
    console.log({ route, pathname })
    if (!route.includes('#') && route !== pathname) {
      push(route)
      const newHistory = history.slice(0, i)
      setHistory(newHistory)
      return
    }
  }
  if (fallbackRoute) {
    router.push(fallbackRoute)
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: So how to get the previous url here on any component ? in the history variable?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez you can use ```const { history, back } = useHistory()```, history is an array of urls

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a very simple way to do this since some of the answers here seem a bit complex for implementing something this simple. `router.back()` doesn't seem to work well in this scenario as, in my case, it'd go all the way back and out of my site some times.
So, I thought , what better way to do this than `localStorage`?

**when I need to send the user to the '/login' route, I add the current route to localStorage**

```tsx
if (!auth.user) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("path", router.asPath);
  router.replace("/login");
  return <div> redirecting to login... </div>;
}
```

**and once the user sign-in, I send them back to the previous page** (the route of which has been saved in the localStorage

```tsx
if (auth.user) {
  router.replace(localStorage.getItem("path") || "/");
  return <div> Loading... </div>
  );
}
```

You can observe the `localStorage` while testing to see what is going on. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say there's a `/profile` page which should be rendered iff user is logged in or else user should be redirected to `/login`, after user login on `/login`, it should be pushed to previous page (here`/profile`) but not on another website or New Tab.

1. In `/profile` this is how you should redirect to `/login`

> `Router.push('/login?referer=profile', '/login')`
>
> [image]

2. In `/login` after user is successfully logged in, use:

> `Router.push(Router.query.referer?.toString||'/')`
>
> [image]

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this problem and used the following solution to route back to the previous page.

In my component I used the `useRouter()` hook from Next.js. This hook produces a router object which has the `back()` function. This function can be used on an `<a>` tag to redirect back in the following way.

```js
const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <a onClick={() => router.back()}>Go back to the last page</a>
    </>
  );
};
```

Note that this function does **not** produce a URL that you can use as a value in the href, which is unfortunate. But I think this solution is simple yet effective.

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerback

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Hook

Add this hook, and call it in your `_app.tsx` or where needed. You can compare it to `router.pathname` if you need to know what the change was.

```tsx
const usePreviousRoute = () => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();

  const ref = useRef<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = asPath;
  }, [asPath]);

  return ref.current;
};
```

This doesn't leave data behind once the page is closed (storage, cookies) and cleanly resets to null on next visit to the site.

Comment: This does not return the previous route that the user was interacting with. All it returns is the current route on the current page, which you can simply achieve using router.asPath.

Answer (score 2):

`src/hooks/use-previous-url.tsx`

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const PreviousURLContext = createContext<React.MutableRefObject<string | null>>({ current: null })

export const PreviousURLProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter()

  const asPathRef = useRef<string | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    asPathRef.current = asPath
  }, [asPath])

  return <PreviousURLContext.Provider value={asPathRef}>{children}</PreviousURLContext.Provider>
}

const usePreviousURL = () => useContext(PreviousURLContext)

export default usePreviousURL
```

`src/pages/_app.tsx`

```js
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { PreviousPathProvider } from '../hooks/use-previous-url'

export default function App(props: AppProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props

  return (
    <PreviousPathProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </PreviousPathProvider>
  )
}
```

`src/pages/foo.tsx`

```js
import usePreviousURL from '../hooks/use-previous-url'

export default function Foo() {
  const previousURL = usePreviousURL().current

  return (
    <p>previous URL: {previousURL}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: JFI: I tried to use it in NextJS 13+, in app dir but did not work. And also when you add `'use client'` to the `use-previous-url.tsx` component it says: "NextRouter was not mounted".

Answer (score 1):

I can not get previous URL but with the code below I can find have a back URL or no:

```tsx
typeof window !== 'undefined' && +window?.history?.state?.idx > 0
```

---

```tsx
const back = async () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && +window?.history?.state?.idx > 0) {
    await Router.back()
  } else {
    await Router.replace(fallbackURL)
  }
}
```

Comment: The `idx` property is missing in the `state`!

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

// in _app.js

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const router = useRouter();

    const [history, setHistory] = useState({ previous: null, current: router.asPath });

    useEffect(() => {
        setHistory((oldHistory) => ({ ...oldHistory, previous: oldHistory.current, current: router.asPath }));
    }, [router.asPath]);

    return (<Component {...{ ...pageProps, history }} />);
}

export default MyApp;

// in a page

function MyPage({ ...pageProps }) {
    return (<span>Previous route: {pageProps.history?.previous || "/"}</span>);
}

export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to use the "referer" (the previous URL) property within the new App router we can implement something like this (from a server side component):

```
import React from "react";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

const index = () => {
  const headersList = headers();
  const referer = headersList.get("referer");

  return (
      <h1>{referer}</h1>
  );
};

export default index;
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers).

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing similar to `iurii`'s answer. My `_app.js` looks like this (I was trying to integrate with segment.com so felt this need)

```
export default class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidMount () {
    const { asPath } = this.props.router;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ history: [...prevState.history, asPath] }));

    const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';

    if(isBrowser) {
      // For the first page load
      console.log("Going to log first load --> referrer : ", document.referrer);
      // this can get me the document.referrer properly, if I come to the website from a third party source like google search.
      global.analytics.page(window.location.href,
        {referrer: document.referrer}
      )
    }
  }

  static async getInitialProps ({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  state = {
    history: [] // keep history items in state
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {

    const { history } = this.state;
    const { asPath } = this.props.router;





    // if current route (`asPath`) does not equal
    // the latest item in the history,
    // it is changed so lets save it
    if (history[history.length - 1] !== asPath) {

      
      global.analytics.page(window.location.href, {
        referrer: history[history.length - 1] ? history[history.length - 1] : ""
      })
      // this simulates the document.referrer on pages after the user navigates
      this.setState(prevState => ({ history: [...prevState.history, asPath] }));
    }
  }
```

So with a combination of `history[history.length - 1] ? history[history.length - 1] : ""`  and `const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';` I am able to simulate document.referrer for all cases. But I am missing one case, suppose , I am at google, my site landing page is A, then A points to B

Then `google to A` --> I get `document.referrer` as `google`

Then `A to B` --> I get `document.referrer` as `A` which is consistent with the behavior.

But Now If I refresh page B, then my `document.referrer` becomes `google` again.

I think I can save the last known previous URL in local storage , but that will be a anti-pattern as the browser back button can correctly take the user to the previous page (`A`), so somewhere the data is there already. Currently I can live with this solution as I only use this for analytics purpose on segment.com and google analytics, so refreshing will mess up my analytics numbers slightly, but still looking forward to a perfect solution so get exact data.

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by [this article](https://www.grouparoo.com/blog/getting-previous-path-nextjs) and decided to create a reusable hook for capturing the previous and the current routes paths. It can be initialized right in the `_app.tsx` file:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSessionStorage } from 'usehooks-ts';

export const useCaptureRoutesPaths = (): void => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [_, setPrevValue] = useSessionStorage('prev-route', '');
  const [currentRoute, setCurrentRoute] = useSessionStorage(
    'current-route',
    '',
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (): void => {
      setPrevValue(currentRoute);
      setCurrentRoute(router.asPath);
    };

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    return () => router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
  }, [
    currentRoute,
    router.asPath,
    router.events,
    setCurrentRoute,
    setPrevValue,
  ]);
};
```

Then I made hooks for obtaining the routes:

```
export const useHistoricalRoutes = (): { prev: string; current: string } => {
  const [prev] = useSessionStorage('prev-route', '');
  const [current] = useSessionStorage('current-route', '');
  return { prev, current };
};
```

And hook for going back to the previous route:

```
export const useGoPrevRoute = (fallbackUrl = '/'): (() => void) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { prev, current } = useHistoricalRoutes();
  const prevRoutePath = prev && prev !== current ? prev : fallbackUrl;

  return () => router.push(prevRoutePath);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who is actually **using NextJs in the 13** version, [you can't use the router.events anymore](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42016). So i create a NextJs Context and Hook to help you handle the code that will be run when user leave some application route.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

type TargetsRouteToHandle = {
    [x: string]: (() => void) | undefined;
};

type NavigationEventContextValue = {
    addTargetRoute: (targetRoute: AddTargetRouteProps) => void;
};

type AddTargetRouteProps = {
    pathName: string;
    hookFunction: TargetsRouteToHandle['x'];
};

const NavigationEventContext = React.createContext<NavigationEventContextValue>(
    {} as NavigationEventContextValue
);

export const useNavigationEvent = () =>
    React.useContext(NavigationEventContext);

function NavigationEventProvider({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
    const pathName = usePathname();

    const pathHistory = React.useRef<[string, string]>(['', pathName]);

    const [targetsRouteToHandle, setTargetsRouteToHandle] =
        React.useState<TargetsRouteToHandle>({});

    const addTargetRoute = ({ pathName, hookFunction }: AddTargetRouteProps) => {
        setTargetsRouteToHandle((prev) => ({ ...prev, [pathName]: hookFunction }));
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const prev = pathHistory.current.at(0) as string;

        const isLeavingATargetRoute = targetsRouteToHandle[prev];

        if (isLeavingATargetRoute) isLeavingATargetRoute();

        pathHistory.current.push(pathHistory.current.shift() as string);

        pathHistory.current.unshift(pathName);

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [pathName]);

    return (
        <NavigationEventContext.Provider value={{ addTargetRoute }}>
            {children}
        </NavigationEventContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default NavigationEventProvider;
```

### Example of use

this way every time the user leave the route '/chat' the code from *hookFunction* will be called, you can create how many *addTargetRoute* you want.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    addTargetRoute({
        pathName: '/chat',
        hookFunction: () => {
            console.log('Trocou a pagina');
        }
    });
}, []);
```

#### Dot forget to wrap your application in the *NavigationEventProvider* provider

```js
import NavigationEventProvider from '@contexts/NavigationEventContext';

function Providers({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <NavigationEventProvider>{children}</NavigationEventProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Are you suggesting that I need to manually add the previous URL each time, for every single page?

Comment: This code acts like a pub/sub pattern, you register a route and a callback then every time the user leave this route the callback will be called, you just need to register the route one time in any page. If you try it out let me know