# How can I get the previous url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to get the previous url in a nextjs project. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript) but it doesn't help because it always prints me the base url (`http://localhost:3000/`) with this method (`document.referrer`). I also tried to push a state into window.history based on official [developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)  doc.

In the last case I click on a link and it redirects me to another page. On this page I need to know where I come from. I tried:

```
//pathname is a string containing the actual pathname
history.pushState({prevPath: pathname},pathname)
```

If I print **history** in the new page then I don't see any *prevState* in the state field.

Comment: history.pushState({foo:bar},'title',pathname) ?

Comment: The last parameter is optional. I tried in this way also but nothing changes.. I always get this: state: {
    "url": "/search?keyword=tag1",
    "as": "/search?keyword=tag1",
    "options": {
        "scroll": true
    },
    "__N": true,
    "idx": 23
}  **state** is the state of history

Comment: ANd with history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", "bar2.html"); ? No trace ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to get history and match in this.props in nextjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65614253/1870780)? Check out the `useRouteUrlHistory` hook implementation in the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a state which is an object that has two properties: `previousUrl` and `currentUrl` like this:

```
const urlReducer = (state={previousUrl: null, currentURL: null},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_URLS":
            return {previousUrl: state.currentUrl, currentUrl: window.location.href}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is dispatch an action in every page you visit like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch({type: "SET_URLS"});
},[]);
```