# Identify the page from where we are navigating to the resulting page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

Let's say there are three pages - A, B, and C.

I can navigate from A to C and from B to C as well, but the view of C depends on the page from which we are navigating.

I would like to know how we can identify in Next.js from which page we are routing to page C.

Page C has a dynamic route

TIA

Comment: You might want to rethink the design here.  Why not have page C accept a URL query parameter which varies its behavior how you want.  Then, not only can you simply generate two different links to C from A and B, but you have a stable URL which you can link to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235122/5833816

Comment: @minism The page C is actually a dynamic route.

Comment: @MohitChauhan Even with a dynamic route, you can append a query parameter.

Comment: @minism yes, but is there any other way doing it, without using query paramter

Comment: Probably, but what's the reasoning?  A query parameter is the standard practice in web design for dynamic page behavior like you've described. Consider that without this, refreshing the page could lose your state.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the previous location as query data:

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: "/some-page",
    query: "current location", // the data
  }}
>
  <a>Some Text</a>
</Link>
```

Then you can retrieve the query data:

```
const router = useRouter();
const data = router.query;
```

If you don't like the idea of passing the previous location as a query, you could save the current location in a global state, like Redux on a page mount, after reading the previous value, which represents the previous location pathname.

Answer (score 0):

You can get advantage of `getServerSideProps` since the function is called on every request.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const from = context.req.headers.referer ;  
  //...

  return {
    props: {
      from,
      //...
    },
  };
}
```

The property `refer` represents the `url` of the page that called your current page.

##### Note: the property `refer` will no exist in `context.req.headers` if the user enters the `URL` manually `props.from` will be passed as `undefined` to the page.

---

Now you have the property `from` available in the `props` object passed to your page you can know from wich `url` the current page is called so you can decide what to do based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a history provider with React [context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). I use it to hide elements on a page when the user comes from another specific page.

1. Create the Provider and the context, and a hook to facilitate the usage:

```
// src/common/providers/history-provider.tsx
import { createContext, FC, ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const HistoryContext = createContext<string[]>([]);

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const HistoryProvider: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory((previous) => [...previous, asPath]);
  }, [asPath]);

  return <HistoryContext.Provider value={history}>{children}</HistoryContext.Provider>;
};

export function useHistory(): string[] {
  return useContext(HistoryContext);
}
```

2. Wrap your application with the provider:

```
// src/pages/_app.tsx
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { RootLayout } from '@/common/layouts/root';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { HistoryProvider } from 'common/providers/history-provider';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <RootLayout>
      <HistoryProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </HistoryProvider>
    </RootLayout>
  );
}
```

3. Use the hook `useHistory` to get the path history in your component:

```
// src/features/x/components/component-x.tsx
export const ComponentX: FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const comingFromAdding = (): boolean => {
    if (history.length < 2) return false;
    return !history.at(-2)?.includes('add');
  };

  if(comingFromAdding()) // do something...
  
  // ...
}
```