# Access the url that user has entered from in getServerSideProps Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently trying to find the page that the user has came from to enter this current one in the server side props, im not sure if thats possible? or are there any ways that i could access that

TLDR: get the url which user is **coming from** and **not** where is **going to**, example:

**coming from**: http://localhost:6060/product/id/55555-62/

**going to**: http://localhost:6060/products/

I would like to access the id query, in the /products/ getServerSideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async ({ req }) => {
  console.log(req);
 

  return {
    props: {},
  };
});
```

Comment: `reg` ? typo? :)

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter

> resolvedUrl: A normalized version of the request URL that strips the _next/data prefix for client transitions and includes original query values.

```
export const getServerSideProps = (ctx) => {...}
```

Inside `ctx` you can find `params, query, resolvedUrl` etc

Comment: But i would like to check the URL that the user is COMING FROM not GOING TO

Answer (score 0):

Would the referrer enough for the thing you needed it for?

```
req.headers.referer
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: This isn't the url that the user entered from. right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235122/15814542