# Dynamic back button with next/route that returns the user to only my website and no other based on how he entered the page

Tags: next.js, next-router

with nextjs I am facing an. issue with the router `back()` function.

**The issue:** is if the user enters the page with an url and clicks the back button, then he will be put back to a previews page. So if I was in, example, youtube.com than in url enter my website address and inside i click back - i will be put back to youutbe.com.

**What I need:** if the user entered the page from some other webiste - the back button should redirect to home page `/`. But if he entered the page while within my page (example in home page clicked `/posts`) then he should be redirected back to the previews page he was on.

I tried using `document.referrer` but its always empty...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565631/how-to-get-previous-url-in-next-js) help answer your question? You can run it conditionally based on the result with `startsWith()` for example.

Comment: server side props. thats right! I forgot that such data is on the server not client. Yes this solves my issue, thx

Comment: Great, I've answered the question. Please tick it to say your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the Referer ( so the previous URL ) in the context of [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) or any other Data fetching methods

as

```
context.req.headers.referer
```

example in code

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.req.headers.referer)
}
```

You can then use conditional logic, for example `.startsWith()` to determine where you would like to send the user, possibly by setting the state on the first render with `useEffect()`.